# passing string to jsp, whats wrong?

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, cytoscape-web

In a Controller, I have a handler method that should pass a string to a jsp named searchResultGraph.jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value = PATHELEM + "/searchGraph")
    public String handleGraph(Model model) {
        String write = writer.getWriteString();
        model.addAttribute("write", write);
        System.out.println(write);
        return PATHELEM + "/searchResultGraph";
    }
```

the jsp looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="core"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Graph View</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/json2.min.js" />"></script> <!-- ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/ -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/cytoscapeweb.min.js" />"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/AC_OETags.min.js" />"></script>


        <script language="JavaScript">
            window.onload=function() {
                        // network data could alternatively be grabbed via ajax
                 var xml = '${write}';

                        // init and draw
                        // initialization options
                            var options = {
                                swfPath: "CytoscapeWeb",
                                flashInstallerPath: "playerProductInstall"
                            };

                            var vis = new org.cytoscapeweb.Visualization("cytoscapeweb", options);

                            var draw_options = {
                                // your data goes here
                                network: xml,

                                // show edge labels too
                                edgeLabelsVisible: false,

                                edgeTooltipsEnabled:true,

                                // let's try another layout
                                layout: "circle",

                                // hide pan zoom
                                panZoomControlVisible: true
                            };

                            vis.draw(draw_options);

                        };
        </script>

        <style>
            /* The Cytoscape Web container must have its dimensions set. */
            html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            #cytoscapeweb { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Graph</h1>
        <h1>${write}</h1>
        <div id="cytoscapeweb">
             Cytoscape Web will replace the contents of this div with your graph.
             ${write}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But nothing is displayed when I try to call `${write}`. Is there something missing in my method?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code that you've given here. I can only ask you to ensure that getWriteString() is actually returning a non empty string

Comment: the string is not empty... that would have been an easy solution! ;)

Comment: Try using c:out instead then. Logically it shouldn't make a difference, but you never know.. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

The links in options-tag had to be relative links too!

So instead of this

```
var options = {
                swfPath: "CytoscapeWeb",
                flashInstallerPath: "playerProductInstall"
              };
```

I had to write this:

```
var options = {
                 swfPath: "<c:url value="/resources/js/CytoscapeWeb" />",
                 flashInstallerPath: "<c:url value="resources/js/playerProductInstall" />"
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

CHECK ARE YOU HAVING A METHOD NAMED getWriteString();   in you bean class and if not create a class name Write and instantiate an object named write in your controller and then pass some string into that and add that to the model to return that by you controller,

```
Write write = new Write();
write.getWriteString();
```

Comment: I have a method named getWriteString(); It would give me some exception if i didn't it... the only problem is, that he doesn't display my string. but it must be somewhere, because if not it would give me a error like: no input found with name write

Comment: Try using `ModelMap` instead. With `addObject()` method